# How to make igraph network more readable in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following sample data (total of 700 observations), code and resulting graph in R. How can I modify the code to make the graph more readable?

The data can be read as "V1 is a follower of V2", on down.

[image]

```
g <- graph.data.frame(graph_subset, directed=TRUE)
plot(g, edge.width=E(g)$weight)
```

[image]

Comment: Too broad, here is [a good tutorial](http://kateto.net/network-visualization), you need to play with size, layout, colours, etc

Comment: Really? You want to plot 70k observations on one graph and have it be readable? What kind of output do you have in mind exactly?

Comment: @MrFlick sorry, it's 700 observations, not 70,000.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @MrFlick's comment and @zx8754. You could also try modifying the layout:

```
plot(g, mode = "circle", edge.width=E(g)$weight)
```

There are several modes to modify the layout: circle, eigen, random, spring, kamadakawi and so on. Kamadakawi is my best option.

Hope it helps!

---

Try:

```
plot(g, layout=layout_in_circle, edge.width=E(g)$weight)
```

this must change the layout, you can also modify the size of vertex with `vertex.cex=1.5` and hide the labels with `displaylabels=F`. There are more commands, find them in the tutorial that @zx8754 mentioned, section 4.2.

Comment: Sorry, its actually 700 observations, not 70k whoops. That code doesn't really change much. Is there any way I can make the bubbles, text. etc smaller? Some data points are 5 digits long. Or maybe spacing everything out some?

Comment: I edited my answer with other options. You should check the tutorial that @zx8754 linked in comments. Hope it helps.